# flutter bloc . what is wrong android studio no error but when i run project

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Exception caught by widgets library:

```
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building _InheritedProviderScope<AppCubit?>(value: <not yet loaded>):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<StateStreamable<Object?>> above this BlocConsumer<StateStreamable<Object?>, Object?> Widget
```

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that BlocConsumer<StateStreamable<Object?>, Object?> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<StateStreamable<Object?>>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

i what is wrong try too make blocprovider

Comment: The question is not clear to me, but seems that at compile time everything is ok, but at runtime u get an exception because context associated to widget was not able to find needed provider. Try to request provider from a child widget, not from widget itself

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using context.read or BlocProvider.of(context) on the same context which you used to define BlocProvider/MultiBlocProvider.

Only the child contexts have knowledge about the AppCubit, you should wrap the child of BlocProvider/MultiBlocProvider inside a LayoutBuilder widget. Rest will remain same. Your app will work.